Actionable Message AdaptiveCard 1.0 Works on Windows Outlook, Android Outlook, not on IOS Outlook
The following will not display on our User's IOS devices upgraded to the latest 4.24 version of Outlook for IOS - 4.2412.0. The documentation here says that it supported on version 4.34 (Which does not exist) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/ . We have significant amount of time invested in leveraging these tools. Please help me understand what would cause this not to work on the software across IOS devices?
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "originator": "my secret not sharing",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "id": "90451e68-1bc7-385b-93f3-eaf1384e282a",
      "text": "HELLO IOS",
      "wrap": true,
      "weight": "Bolder",
      "size": "ExtraLarge"
    }
  ],
  "padding": "None"
}

It works everywhere except IOS.

By the way this same functionality worked just fine like 2 weeks ago on iPhone!
